# How to prevent concurrent streaming

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, against

I have written an app for a radio station, that is working well. If I click to go back to the desktop and click to activate the application again, it causes the app to stream again, resulting in 2 streams running concurrently.

Here is my code;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.setTitle("Standart FM");

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBasla);
    facebookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebook);
    twitterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwitter);
    Intent myService = new Intent(this, MyMediaPlayerService.class);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    if (isOnline()) {

        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        pd.show();

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer
                .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    } else {
        ....
    }

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MyMediaPlayerService.class);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.andplaybtn);
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            } else {
                startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.andstopbtn);

                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
                    pd.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer
                        .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                pd.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

}

 }
```

How do I solve this problem? How to prevent concurrent streaming in this Activity? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop your media player in onPause method, and also say mediaPlayer=null;

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer=null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.How can I do that in these codes?I have written onPause() method and called mediaPlayer.stop(), then I instead of mediaPlayer.stop() I have written onPause().Is it right?An also where can i write mediaPlayer=null ?

Comment: I have edited the answer for you to see. This is what you need to add. Also i recommend you to read this, it will give you an insight why is this happening and what you need to look after in future development. Good Luck!  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: :( But it is finishing the application.I want to attend the application  and if I click the back for going to desktop and then again click to application , it won't stream again.

Comment: When you click back button you are "shutting down" your application. As the result when you start the app you are starting the app from the begging calling onCreate. But if you click the Home button, and then start the app you are calling onResume, but not onCreate. That's why you need to carefully plan your code based on the behavior you want to get.